# cometd bayeux: handling user disconnection properly on page unload

Tags: cometd

Current setup: cometD servlet with jQuery cometd plugin.

Let's say i have a simple chat room that currently has 2 users (userA and userB) connected to it.  When userB navigates away from the page, I need userA to be notified that userB has left the room.  Is there a way to let userA know that userB left without using the `unload` handler?

> $(window).unload(function(){
>         /** lets notify other users that currentUserId left **/
>
> });

After conducting lots of tests; the above code block is not reliable.

The only solution i can think of is using a setInterval where every 1 minute, the admin will loop through an array of connected user, then "pings" them to check whether or not they're still connected.

Any ideas?  Should i use the setInterval polling technique?

Comment: Hello ryan. I am having the same problem, and it is strange that the Cometd library doesn't solve it in the first place. Did you find an answer? it will be very helpfull to me. Thanks

Comment: Hi Yaron, i just added an answer to this post.  Hope you find it helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this who are interested.

You can register a "removeListener" method when a server expires a user's session.

```
    client.addListener(new ServerSession.RemoveListener() {
        public void removed(ServerSession session, boolean timeout){
            members.values().remove(session.getId());
            broadcastMembers(members.keySet());
        }
    });
```

Full code example:
[ChatService.java#handleMembership](http://svn.cometd.org/tags/2.0.0/cometd-java/cometd-java-examples/src/main/java/org/cometd/examples/ChatService.java#handleMembership)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I know this question is old, but why not simply using the PresenceListener?